# Choosing proper heuristic for A* algorithm in subway network

Tags: path-finding, a-star, heuristics

Currently I am developing pathfinding module for subway network. I have question about admissible heuristic.

**Prerequisites:**

Graph is weighted. You can move only on edges (tunnels between stations in real life)

Map have size 3000 x 2500 pixels.
I have nodes and available edges with their weight (in seconds) – adjacency list.

Nodes contains this attributes:

- **id** – unique identifier
- **name** – subway station name
- **x** – X position on map
- **y** – Y position on map
- **lineId** – line id

So right now I`m using Euclidean distance, but it seems like not a good option, because it gives wrong results for stations that is near each other, but on different lines.

For example:

[example situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDrPS.png)

Stations A and B is near each other and Euclidian distance gives us value of 200.

But the actual path weight is 1600. Because we can move only by available edges.

Finally, I tried to use ALT preprocessing and it gives close results.

But I think that my heuristic function is wrong for such case at all.

I tried to use ALT preprocessing and it gives close results.

Expecting to find proper heuristic function for my project.

Comment: *"because it gives wrong results for stations that is near each other, but on different lines."*: even if the heuristic is much too optimistic, it should not lead to wrong results. If you get wrong (non-optimal) paths then the problem is not with this heuristic, but something else.

Comment: I receive proper results, but thinking about better. Currently I also use k-shortest path also to find next better ones.

Comment: If you receive correct results (even though your write in your question you get *wrong* results??), then the question is off topic for Stack Overflow. If you confirm the results are correct, and are only asking for a review of your code in order to make it better in terms of efficiency, elegance, best practice, ... then you could consider visiting [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but make sure to read their guidelines, which are different from those of Stack Overflow.